# Seeking Code Generator for Spring Web Application

Tags: java, spring, code-generation, template-engine

I have been vetting the process of Code Generators online. I started my search with a promising but not popular Eclipse plugin called FastCode (http://www.3pintech.com/products/fast-code/).

It had a higher learning curve with a tradeoff for flexibility. That was find for me because a lot of our application follows a certain standard that I would need to maintain with the generated code. Unfortunately it was very buggy and I think it may be a dead project.

On to SpringFuse. This looked promising, but I have a few problem with it.

1) We are far into our project development lifecycle and I only need to use it for a subset of new tables in our MYSql database. Springfuse seems to take a "let us generate your entire application" approach.

2) We don't use Hibernate and SpringFuse seems to be tied into this

3) It doesn't seem to be that configurable

What I would like to do is start with a database table, and from there generate a corresponding POJO, DAO for CRUD operations, Service Layer to call the DAO and a Unit test for testing each layer. We have a standard pattern for creating our DAO layer that I will be using.

I am considering using Perl or maybe another templating system to do this but that will involve a significant amount of coding on my part. I was wondering if the SO community knows of any good technologies to use here.

I actually think an online sevice would be awesome here, something like the awesome JSON2POJO, but I don't think it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the solution that worked best for me was to use the FreeMarker Java Template Engine and write my own code generation system. Using regular expressions to parse our database file and converting some of our existing code into FreeMarker templates only took a couple of days and yielded a system that is going to save us a lot of time.

I recommend this approach to users who are in a similar spot for highly customized Enterprise Applications. Most of the rendered code is not fit for primetime, but the base boilerplate code I'm generating results in huge time-savings.

FreeMarker's templating system is very similar to other technologies like JSTL and it throws very descriptive error messages so designing the templates was very simple.